# Count number of duplicate instances in js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I'm running a ajax call to retrieve values from a JSON structure. For each iteration i add values to a js array with `.push`. There are multiple instances of the same value (e.g. the name of a person). What i want is to count the number of identical names and remove them afterwards.

The main goal is to plot them in a chart afterwards, showing the name of a person and the number of time s he/she is represented in the array.

My code:

```
var arr = [];

$.each(data.d.results, function (a, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://helpdesk.monjasa.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.RequesterId + ")/CreatedBy",
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            },
            success: function (data2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://helpdesk.monjasa.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests(" + data.AssignedToId + ")/AssignedTo",
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                    },
                    success: function (data3) {
                        $(".inner").prepend('<p>' + data.Request + ' <br>Submitted by: ' + data2.d.Name + '<br>Assigned to: ' + data3.d.Name + ' | Due in: ' + data.DueInDays + ' day(s)</p>');
                        arr.push(data3.d.Name);
                        console.log(arr);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery select unique item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698499/jquery-select-unique-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the counts while pushing to array only and do not push if already present.

```
var arr = [];
var counts = [];
$.each(data.d.results, function(a, data) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://helpdesk.monjasa.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests("+data.RequesterId+")/CreatedBy",
        headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
        success: function(data2){ 

            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://helpdesk.monjasa.com/IT/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ITHelpdeskRequests("+data.AssignedToId+")/AssignedTo",
                    headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
                    success: function(data3){

                            $(".inner").prepend('<p>'+data.Request +' <br>Submitted by: '+data2.d.Name+'<br>Assigned to: '+data3.d.Name+' | Due in: '+data.DueInDays+' day(s)</p>');    

                    var indexOfName = arr.indexOf(data3.d.Name);
                    if(indexOfName == -1) {
                            arr.push(data3.d.Name);
                            counts.push(1);
                            console.log(arr);
                    }
                    else {
                            counts[indexOfName]++;
                    }

                    }  
                });

    }  
});
```

Comment: Thx that did it. Any suggestions on how I would concat the two arrays in a way that would merge them every second time. Example `array 1 =[1,2,3] array 2 = ['Thomas', 'Christian','Tim']` to `array_final = ['name':'Thomas', 'number': 1] ?`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check for duplicates is to load an object, something like this:

```
// Ode to joy:
var a = [3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2];

// Then count them
var count = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  v = a[i];
  if (count[i] === undefined) count[i] = 0;
  count[i]++
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the magic

```
    function getCounts(arr) {
        var i = arr.length, // var to loop over
            result = {}; // obj to store results
        while (i) result[arr[--i]] = (result[arr[i]] || 0) + 1; // count occurrences
        return result;
    }

    function getCount(word, arr) {
        return getCounts(arr)[word] || 0;
    }

    getCount('Ehsan', yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an additional object to receive the person names and their occurrences.

```
var arr = [], persons = {};
```

Then your inner `success`-callback may be:

```
success: function (data3) {
    var name = data3.d.Name;
    $(".inner").prepend('<p>' + data.Request + ' <br>Submitted by: ' + data2.d.Name + '<br>Assigned to: ' + data3.d.Name + ' | Due in: ' + data.DueInDays + ' day(s)</p>');
    if (name in persons) persons[name]++;
    else arr.push(name), persons[name] = 1;
}
```

Afterwards you can show the persons and their occurences:

```
for (var n in persons) console.log(n + ': ', persons[n]);
```